# How to make large calculations program faster

Tags: c++, performance, mathematical-optimization

I'm implementing a compression algorithm. Thing is, it is taking a second for a 20 Kib files, so that's not acceptable. I think it's slow because of the calculations.
 I need suggestions on how to make it faster. I have some tips already, like shifting bits instead of multiplying, but I really want to be sure of which changes actually help because of the complexity of the program. I also accept suggestions concerning compiler options, I've heard there is a way to make the program do faster mathematical calculations.

Common operations are:

- `pow`(...) function of `math` library
- large number % 2
- large number multiplying

Edit: the program has no floating point numbers

Comment: What kind of numbers are you calculating? Floating point numbers or integers?

Comment: Just integers. No floating point.

Comment: Why are you using `pow()` with integers ?

Comment: You need a profiler - what is you chipset (Intel, AMD) on your development machine, is it Windows or linux?

Comment: Okay, well gprof is a free profiler on linux, and gcov gives coverage information (lcov makes a nice gui).  Had you said AMD I would have recommended CodeAnalyst (free by athlon but only works on AMD) over gprof as its a bit more user friendly.  I'm not sure if Intel provide a profiler for their chips (free?).

Comment: Ah, you have to pay for Intel's vtune - there is 30 day trial only.

Comment: Have you asked your compiler to optimize? Are you testing release mode (not debug?)

Comment: As has been said, profile. But you might also want to try Intel's compiler, icc. For some programs, you can gain a *lot* of performance; I've seen 50+% gains for computational programs. I think there is a free (not open) version, but I can't find it on their website. I got it from Gentoo's portage some time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question of *how to make things faster* should not be asked here to other people, but rather in your environment to a profiler. Use the profiler to determine where most of the time is spent, and that will hint you into which operations need to be improved, then if you don't know how to do it, ask about specific operations. It is almost impossible to say what you need to change without knowing what your original code is, and the question does not provide enough information: *pow(...)* function: what are the arguments to the function, is the exponent fixed? how much precision do you need? can you change the function for something that will yield a similar result? *large number*: how large is *large* in *large number*? what is *number* in this context? integers? floating point?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad, without enough informaiton to give you concrete advise, we have to do with a general roadmap.

What platform, what compiler? What is "large number"? What have you done already, what do you know about optimization?

- Test a release build with optimization (/Ox /LTCG in Visual C++, -O3 IIRC for gcc)
- Measure where time is spent - disk access, or your actual compression routine?
- Is there a better algorithm, and code flow? The fastest operation is the one not executed.
- for 20K files, memory working set should not be an issue (unless your copmpression requries large data structures), so so code optimization are the next step indeed
- a modern compiler implements a lot of optimizations already, e.g replacing a division by a power-of-two constant with a bit shift.
- `pow` is very slow for native integers
- if your code is well written, you may try to post it, maybe someone's up to the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Hints :-
1) modulo 2 works only on the last bit.
2) power functions can be implemented in logn time, where n is the power. (Math library should be fast enough though). Also for fast power [you may check this out](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/)

If nothing works, just check if there exists some fast algorithm.

Comment: 1) So when I do X % 2, the program will return the value of its first bit? So it's not slow. 2) I'm using pow from the math library btw